# Are integral extensions of a catenary ring still catenary?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, krull-dimension

A (commutative unitary) Noetherian ring $R$ of finite dimension is said to be catenary if for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ one has $\mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak{p})+\mathrm{dim}(R/\mathfrak{p})=\mathrm{dim}R$.

Let $A$ be a catenary ring and $B$ a finite extension of $A$ (*id est* $A\subseteq B$ and $B$ is a finite $A$-module). Is $B$ a catenary ring?

Comment: Is your definition of *catenary* equivalent to the usual one (that requires that for all primes $p \subsetneq q$ all maximal prime chains $p \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq q$ have the same length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Nagata's famous family of examples of non-catenary rings yields a non-catenary finite extension of a catenary noetherian local domain.

**Reference:** M. Nagata, [*On the chain problem of prime ideals*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118799769), Nagoya Math. J. 10 (1956), 51-64.

Comment: A simple counterexample is given by $A$ $=$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and $B$ $=$ $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+X,2X)$. Cf. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/430039).